# Testing asynchronous Redux action with fetch mock and converting to json

Tags: asynchronous, redux, fetch

I am quite happily testing asynchronous Redux actions, but am completely stumped by one quite simple situation. Here is my function:

```
//actions.js
export const fetchInfo = (credentials) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(asyncRequest())
    const fetchConfig = {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        email: credentials.email,
        token: credentials.token
      })
    }
    return fetch('api/info', fetchConfig)
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          return response.json()
            .then((json) => {
              console.log(json)
              dispatch(receiveInfoSuccess(json))

    } else if (response.status === 401) {
      dispatch(push('/signin'))
  },
  error => {
    dispatch(receiveInfoFailure(error))
  })
  }
}
```

If I test my status 401 case, everything is fine, but for some reason I cannot get the test to run past `response.json()`. Here is my test:

```
it('should use fetchInfo to dispatch relevant action creators', (done) => {
const credentials = {"email": "e@d.com", "token": "djbsdJ"}
const fetchReturnVal = {
  status: 200,
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  body: {
      "id": "kjbsdf"
    }
}
fetchMock.post('api/info', fetchReturnVal)

const expectedActions = [
  {type: 'ASYNC_REQUEST'},
  {type: 'RECEIVE_INFO_SUCCESS',
    payload: {
      id: 'kjbsdf'
    }
  }
]

function mockDispatch(action) {
  const expectedAction = expectedActions.shift()
  expect(action).toEqual(expectedAction)

  if (!expectedActions.length) {
    done()
  }
}
actions.fetchLogin(credentials)(mockDispatch)
})
```

The test always times out with `Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.` and the code never runs into the `.then` block.

How do I get the `response.json` promise to resolve? I have tried things like including the following key in fetch return value:

```
json: () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     resolve({"id": "example"}) 
  })
}
```

....but this just times out as well